# Rest - How to send Http Error Response Without Stack Trace

Tags: java, rest, web-services, spring-mvc

I have an rest web service. If any exception thrown, web service return http 500 error. But I don't want to send this error response with exception stack trace. I just want to send with error code and error message. I didn't achieve this. How can I do this?

I already tried @ControllerAdvice and @ExceptionHandler annotations but I couldn't. When I used @ResponseStatus annotation, always send static "reason" value. How can I set this value? Thank for your help.

```java
public class SendMessageController{
    private Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(getClass());
    @Autowired
    private QueueService queueService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/message/check", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers={ "content-type=application/json"})
    public @ResponseBody
    ApiResponse sendMessage(@RequestBody String requestMessage) throws Exception {
        try {
            return new ApiResponse(queueService.processRequestForJSONString(requestMessage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new GenericException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, e.getMessage());
            //throw e;
        }
    }

    @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, reason="Exception Message")
    public class GenericException extends Exception {
        public HttpStatus httpCode;
        public String errorMessage;

        public GenericException(HttpStatus httpCode, String errorMessage){
            this.httpCode = httpCode;
            this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
            //I can't set "reason"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible solutions and I'm pretty sure an ErrorHandler is a much better way to go.

```
@GetMapping(value="/{empId}", produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)    
public ResponseEntity<EmployeeInfoItem> getEmployeeInfo(@PathVariable("empId") Integer empId) {
    try {
        ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error( e.getMessage() );
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FAILED_DEPENDENCY).build();
    }
}
```